# I keep getting extra space on my website how do I solve this?

Tags: html, css

I have tried changing my entire webpage and using different codes but for some reason I am still getting extra white space on the right side of my webpage. My navbar is not being affected but the rest of the page is.

Can anyone please help me or even point out any incorrect code?

I've included in the banner html and css as well as the html and css for my container.

```
        <!--Banner-->

        <div class="banner">
            <a id="ordinary"><img class="banner-image" src="./Images/hero-image.png"/></a>
        </div>

    /* Banner */

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.banner > .banner-image {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

<!--Products-->

        <div id="products" class="container">
            <div class="row-1">
                <div class="box-1">
                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h5>THE ORDINARY</h5>
                            <h4>Squalene Cleanser</h4>
                            <h4>50ml</h4>
                            <p>5.50 GBP</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="btn" src="./Images/shopping-basket-icon.jpeg" width="30px" height="25px"/>
                    </div>
                    <img class="item" src="./Images/cleanser.png" alt="Cleanser">
                </div>
                <div class="box-2">
                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h5>THE ORDINARY</h5>
                            <h4>Glycolic Acid 7% Toning Solution</h4>
                            <h4>240ml</h4>
                            <p>6.80 GBP</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="btn" src="./Images/shopping-basket-icon.jpeg" width="30px" height="25px"/>
                    </div>
                    <img class="item" src="./Images/toner.png" alt="Toner">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-2">
                <div class="box-3">
                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h5>THE ORDINARY</h5>
                            <h4>Hyaluronic Acid 2% + B5</h4>
                            <h4>30ml</h4>
                            <p>5.90 GBP</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="btn" src="./Images/shopping-basket-icon.jpeg" width="30px" height="25px"/>
                    </div>
                    <img class="item" src="./Images/hyaluronic-acid.png" alt="Hyaluronic Acid">
                </div>
                <div class="box-4">
                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h5>THE ORDINARY</h5>
                            <h4>Natural Moisturizing Factors + HA</h4>
                            <h4>30ml</h4>
                            <p>4.90 GBP</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="btn" src="./Images/shopping-basket-icon.jpeg" width="30px" height="25px"/>
                    </div>
                    <img class="item" src="./Images/moisturiser.png" alt="Moisturiser">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-3">
                <div class="box-5">
                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h5>THE ORDINARY</h5>
                            <h4>Caffiene Solution 5% + EGCG</h4>
                            <h4>30ml</h4>
                            <p>5.80 GBP</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="btn" src="./Images/shopping-basket-icon.jpeg" width="30px" height="25px"/>
                    </div>
                    <img class="item" src="./Images/eye-cream.png" alt="Caffiene Eye Serum">
                </div>
                <div class="box-6">
                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h5>THE ORDINARY</h5>
                            <h4>AHA 30% BHA 2% Peeling Solution</h4>
                            <h4>30ml</h4>
                            <p>6.30 GBP</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="btn" src="./Images/shopping-basket-icon.jpeg" width="30px" height="25px"/>
                    </div>
                    <img class="item" src="./Images/chemical-exfoliant.png" alt="Chemical Exfoliant">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


/* Products */

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    width: 2000px;
}

.row-1, .row-2, .row-3 {
    display: flex;
    flex: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid rgb(180, 179, 179);
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    height: 90%;
    width: 80%;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.text {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

p {
    font-weight: bold;
}

p:hover {
    color: grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h5, h4, p {
    width: 200px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

Comment: is this actual code you have?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you share code snippet or any link where you deploy your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on the first line of your CSS file:

This helps you to remove all of the **margin & padding applied by default** on your webpage.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```